# RxJS Emitting Subscribe Twice | webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, rxjs

Code:

```
import { fromEvent, EMPTY } from 'rxjs'
import {map, debounceTime, tap, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, catchError, filter, mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators'
import {ajax} from 'rxjs/ajax'
import css from './styles.css'

const url = ' https://api.github.com/search/users?q='
const input = document.querySelector('.input')
const result = document.querySelector('.result-container')

const stream$ = fromEvent(input, 'input').pipe(
    map(value => value.target.value),
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    filter(v => v.trim()),
    switchMap(value => ajax.getJSON(url + value).pipe(
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
    )),
    map(items => items.items),
    mergeMap(item => item)
)

stream$.subscribe(value => {
   console.log(value)
})
```

And What I'm getting same object twice:
EX:
`Abdugafor index.js.35 Abdugafor VM1023 index.js.35`

how can I fix it?

I don't know what is the problem, but I inspected for second responce and it was webpack code.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.  Are you expecting only 1 emission?

Comment: I am making a request and I'am expecting to get user's. But I'm getting one person two times. For e.x I search 'Abdugafor' - github profile , than I'll get `{Abdugafor} , {Abdugafor}`,  instead of only {Abdugafor} (1 time)

Comment: The reason for two emissions is because of the `mergeMap(item => item)`. Try removing that line. However, it doesn’t explain why you see duplicate results unless they are in your http response. Can you verify the content of your response is what you expect.